# Como descobrir o tipo de relacionamento entre duas tabelas

Tags: entity-framework

Olá, pessoal

Queria saber um jeito, ou melhor, se tem como descobrir através de um SELECT o tipo de relacionamento entre duas tabelas queria que me retornasse.

```
SELECT TABELA_PRINCIPAL, TABELA_RELACIONADA, COLUNA_PRINCIPAL, COLUNA_RELACIONADA, TIPO_RELACIONAMENTO FROM (...)
```

em `TIPO_RELACIONAMENTO` poderia vir como flag (1 = Um para Um, 2 = Um para muitos e 3 Muitos para Muitos, 4 sem relacionamento). Isso á para banco MySql e Sql Server.

Pois estou desenvolvendo um gerador de classes *Models* particular em *Console Application*. Talvez vocês possam se perguntar, "por que não usar Code First com Engenharia Reversa?", pois bem estou fazendo um particular por que nesta minha *Console Application* eu consigo  tratar o nome da classe e o nome das colunas por questões de convenção, já o Code First com Engenharia Reversa não faz isso: ele simplesmente gera as classes a partir do banco com os nome das tabelas do banco, e dependendo do nome das tabelas sai cada caca na model, entendem?

Meu gerador já esta gerando a camada de acesso com Repository Pattern Generic, *Models* com os *Mappers* e *DataAnotation*, tudo automático, só que elas simplemente nao vem com os relacionamentos dentro das classes Mappers. Precisava disso.

Estou fazendo na unha pois ainda nao consegui saber como é feito o processo de Leitura dos schemas e relationship do banco através do Fluent Api.

Quem puder ajudar fico agradecido.

Comment: Ja tentou modificar os padrões da entity? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/custom-conventions-codefirst.aspx

Comment: Ola, vou dar uma olhada, e volto a comentar dai!, obrigado!